# use .call(this) in coffescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

While bare compiling CoffeScript to better understand it, I started wondering how I can write the wrapper function

```
(function(){

}).call(this)
```

using CoffeScript.

I know I could just compile it the way it is supposed to, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling:

```
console.log('Try');
```

in CoffeeScript 1.6.3 gives:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  console.log('Try');

}).call(this);
```

Try here: http://www.compileonline.com/try_coffeescript_online.php

or if you'd rather have the bare one, compile:

```
#blank
```

gives:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {


}).call(this);
```

**In case the --bare option is turned on, you can use:**

```
( -> ) .call(this)
```

which gives:

```
(function() {}).call(this);
```

Try it here: http://coffeescript.org/ (Try coffee tab.)

Comment: you might wanna check the -b option [here](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/command.html)

Comment: `$coffee -c -p main.coffee` is what I am using

Comment: yeah, and that works but if you add -b (`$coffee -c -b -p main.coffee`) it omits the wrapper function. And that's what I am doing.

Comment: but that would only make sense if you want to do something within it.

Comment: http://coffeescript.org/ - if you see here, the first example generates it. But only because it is used as an IIFE.

Comment: Not really. While learning a new language you should explore all the functions and features. I won't probably need nor use that, but that does not mean I'm relieved from knowing it.

Comment: :) I understand. Answer updated to include case where --bare option is enabled.